# Android App Crashes When Start Button is Clicked

Tags: android, button, android-activity, crash

im trying to develop a game in android, however im kinda newbie yet ! Anyways my game consists of two Activities (1. The main menu 2. The game ) . The game starts with the main menu activity and when the user clicks the button with ID= ( button2 ) it should initiate the second activity of the game : 
Here is the .xml code of my MainMenu :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainMenu"
android:background="@drawable/starting_page">

<Button
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:text="Exit Game"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:background="#f6d89d00"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="39dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:text="Start Game"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:background="#f6d86d00"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sound"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button"
    android:enabled="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and he is the so far code in this activity:

```
package com.example.user.catchthefly;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity; 
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.graphics.Color;
import static android.graphics.Color.*;

public class MainMenu extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
    final Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    final Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            finish();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, MainGame.class);
            MainMenu.this.startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

and below i provide the AndroidManifest.xml just in case you need to it to sum up whats wrong:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.user.catchthefly" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainMenu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainGame"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ScorePage"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

logcat

```
07-21 13:50:53.828      811-811/com.example.user.catchthefly E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-21 13:50:55.478      811-811/com.example.user.catchthefly D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 55K, 7% free 2564K/2740K, paused 36ms, total 39ms
07-21 13:50:55.588      811-811/com.example.user.catchthefly D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 6% free 2901K/3080K, paused 26ms, total 27ms
07-21 13:50:55.868      811-811/com.example.user.catchthefly D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
07-21 13:50:55.888      811-811/com.example.user.catchthefly D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a154d08, tid 811
07-21 13:50:55.938      811-811/com.example.user.catchthefly D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
07-21 13:50:55.979      811-811/com.example.user.catchthefly D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
07-21 13:50:56.308      811-811/com.example.user.catchthefly W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-21 13:50:56.328      811-811/com.example.user.catchthefly D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
07-21 13:50:56.548      811-814/com.example.user.catchthefly D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 359K, 14% free 2937K/3416K, paused 6ms+46ms, total 117ms
07-21 13:51:49.189      811-811/com.example.user.catchthefly D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
07-21 13:51:49.199      811-811/com.example.user.catchthefly W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
07-21 13:51:49.229      811-811/com.example.user.catchthefly E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.catchthefly/com.example.user.catchthefly.MainGame}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1839)
            at com.example.user.catchthefly.MainGame.<init>(MainGame.java:25)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The problem is that when i start the program all goes normally but when i click the button "Start Game" (with id ( Button2 ) ) the game crashes in the emulator ...
I have spent hours trying to find out whats wrong but i cant seem to spot the problem 
so any help is welcomed
thank you very much!!!

**SOLUTION :**
i had initiated the buttons , layouts , textviews , imageviews in the MainGame.class above the onCreate method thats why the program crashed 
thank you for your answers :)

Comment: Post your logcat then...

Comment: try using just `startActivity(intent)` instead of `MainMenu.this.start...`

Comment: Post your logcat here, and check your all activity in n same package ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1839)
  at com.example.user.catchthefly.MainGame.<init>(MainGame.java:25)
```

In `MainGame`, you're calling `findViewById()` too early when initializing member variables.

Move the `findViewById()` to `onCreate()` after `setContentView()`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using

```
btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        finish();
        System.exit(0);
    }
});
```

Here `finish();` is nothing but you are trying to close the current activity and `System.exit(0):` is nothing but you are going out from the application.

And change btn1 code to like this:

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, MainGame.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

change this code....

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, MainGame.class);
        MainMenu.this.startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
});
```

to this...

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, MainGame.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }
});
```

Comment: Can you explain *why* you think your code should help the OP (or anyone else with the same problem)?

Comment: nothing but only syntax changes..once working with context object and another one is directly calling `startActivity()`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change the id value for both buttons:

```
final Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
final Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
```

On a side note: You tell right here that you want to stop the current activity and quit the application:

```
btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        finish();
        System.exit(0);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think MainGame code has some problem other wise post your log cat with filter error.
But I recomend to check the code of MainGame class

Answer (score 0):

In your code you call `System.exit(0)` which causes the VM to stop running and the program to exit with the given exit status. Taken from [here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html) In other words this will close your app. What you are trying to do is close just the activity which is done by calling `finish()` which you can see the use and desciption [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

Also in your button 2 on click code you are not starting any activity. To start an activity just add the line like you did in your button 1 code with the fromActivity and the toActivity. Then start it with `startActivity(intent)`.

Your code should like something like this...

```
btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, MainGame.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

I'm not sure what your second button is intended to do but the MainMenu if its your main activity is already started and does not needed to be started with `startActivity()` since you are already there.

Also as a side note, your button names should represent what they should be used for so you can read the code easily. Using `goToGame` or `goToMainMenu` would be easier people to keep track of.